# Adding a JTabbedPane to a JTabbedPane error

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtabbedpane, absolutelayout

Getting this error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at Project.reportpane.addComponent(reportpane.java:69)

I'm unable to add the rptinvestment tabbedPane to the panel tabinvestment

public class reportpane extends JPanel {

```
JTabbedPane rpt;
JPanel tabcashflow;
JPanel tabinvestment;
JPanel tabexchangerates;
JTabbedPane rptinvestment;
JPanel tabofficial;
JPanel tabdem;
JPanel tabcommodities;

public reportpane() {

    rpt = new JTabbedPane();
    tabcashflow = new JPanel();
    tabinvestment = new JPanel();
    tabexchangerates = new JPanel();

    tabofficial = new JPanel();
    tabdem = new JPanel();
    tabcommodities = new JPanel();


    rpt.add("Cashflow", tabcashflow);
    rpt.add("Investement", tabinvestment);
    rpt.add("Exchange rates", tabexchangerates);
    rpt.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    rpt.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    rpt.setTabPlacement(javax.swing.JTabbedPane.TOP);
    rpt.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    rpt.setSize(750, 500);


    rptinvestment = new JTabbedPane();
    rptinvestment.add("Official", tabofficial);
    rptinvestment.add("DEM", tabdem);
    rptinvestment.add("Commodities", tabcommodities);
    rptinvestment.setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 255));
    rptinvestment.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    rptinvestment.setTabPlacement(JTabbedPane.TOP);
    rptinvestment.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());
    rptinvestment.setSize(750, 500);

    addComponent(tabinvestment, rptinvestment, 0, 0, 675, 570);
    addComponent(this, rpt, 10, 10, 675, 570);



    this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    this.setBorder(null);
    this.revalidate();
    this.repaint();

}

public void addComponent(Container container, Component c, int x, int y, int width, int height) {
    c.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
    container.add(c);
}
```

}

Comment: are you initializing your panels like `tabinvestment` in your code before adding or referring to it? Cause I can't see it, have you omitted that part of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never initialize tabinvestment. You declare it as an instance variable, but you never initialize it in the constructor. At some point you need to call `JTabbedPane tabinvestment = new JTabbedPane()`.

Comment: still its not appearing as it should have been, please look into it,
i have edited the code

Answer (score 2):

Your attempting to add components using absolute positioning which is been overridden by the layout manager

JTabbedPane uses its own layout logic and unless your really ever to create your own UI class, can't be changed.

Equally, you've set the frames layout manager to BorderLayout, which will override any positioning values may have set (previously to otherwise)

Comment: so what should i actually do, please recommend

Comment: The question is. What are your trying to achieve

Comment: i have a main JTabbed pane with tabs cashflow, investment and exchange rate,, below investment pane i have two sub tabs mainly official, dem, and commodities